# Axios is unable to get the response data after posting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to use axios to post data and trying to fetch response from it but it is able to successfully post data but unable to print the response data.I have tried in postman it give me the correct response.Is  the problem arising from the backend or the front.
I tried formatting json data and various other ways still no luck

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {browserHistory} from "react-router"
import image from '../Images/jeff.gif'

    import '../styles/auth.css'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {authProfile} from '../actions/authaction'
    import{getProfile} from '../actions/profileaction'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    class SignUp extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.handleLogin=this.handleLogin.bind(this)

        }

        handleLogin(event) {
          event.preventDefault()



        const email = event.target.elements.email.value
        const password=event.target.elements.password.value
        axios.post('http://ec2-3-16-156-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/user/login', {
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        .then(res=> {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });



        }




        handleSubmit(event) {
          event.preventDefault()


        const username = event.target.elements.name.value
        const email = event.target.elements.email.value
        const password=event.target.elements.password.value


        console.log(this.props.getProfile({"Name":username}))



        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://ec2-3-16-156-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/signup',
          data:{
            "email":email,
            "password":password,
            "username":username


          }

        })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)


      }).then((result)=>
      {
        console.log(result)
        this.props.getProfile({"Name":username})
        this.props.authProfile();





      })

    }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>

            <div id="login-box">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>
    <h2> Fakestagram </h2>

 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
 <input type ="text" placeholder="Username" name="name"/>
 <input type ="text" placeholder="email" name="email"/>
 <input type="text" placeholder="password"name="password"/>
 <button> Sign up </button>
 </form>
 </div>

  <div className="right">



    <span className="loginwith">Login with email and password<br />social network</span>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}> 
 <input type ="text" placeholder="email" name="email"/>
 <input type="text" placeholder="password"name="password"/>
 <button> Login </button>
 </form>
 </div>






  </div>
  <div className="or">OR</div>
</div>

        )
      }
    } 

    const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
      posts:state.post.posts,
      profiles:state.profile.profile ,
      auth:state.authStatus.status     //this can be accessed as props by main class
  });

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,{authProfile,getProfile}) (SignUp);
```

Express Back end

```
      router .post("/login",(req,res,next)=>{
           User.find({email:req.body.email}).exec().then(user=>{
            if(user.length<1)
            {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message:"Failure"
                });
            }
           bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user[0].password,(err,result)=>{
                if(err)
                {
                    return res.status(401).json({
                        message:'Auth fail'
                    });
                }
          if(result)
                {
                   const token= jwt.sign({
                        email:user[0].email,
                        userId:user[0]._id
                    },"passwordds",{expiresIn:"1h"});
                    return res.status(200).json({

                        "message":"Auth successful",
                        "token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6IjEyMzQiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI1Y2UyOTU5ZmI5NWM5YjUxMjdlOWY0MmIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTgzNjQ3MjgsImV4cCI6MTU1ODM2ODMyOH0.fkLICMslibkJww8Vw2ghlomggdyDroG-pK3c8TQWowI",
                        "userId":"5ce2959fb95c9b5127e9f42b",
                        "username":"12348999"

                    });
                }
            res.status(401).json({
            message:"Auth failed"
                })
            });


           })
           .catch(err=>{
               console.log(err);
               res.status(500).json({
                   error:err
               })
           })
       })
```

Comment: What is the issue? It's giving the response. Here is the link where I tested: https://repl.it/repls/VirtualCompetitivePress

Comment: @ShubhamVerma well it should return the userid and token but i am unable to access them, works fine in postman though.Is it because of CORS not being enabled

Comment: What is the response from your browser console? Also try using arrow functions with promises: `.then(d => console.log(d.data))`

Comment: when i try to console.log it shows undefined but ,in postman it returns the correct information . you can check with eg  email :1234 and password :1234

Comment: @MickVader — The functions don't use `this`, so switching to an arrow function won't make any difference

Comment: @CryBaby — "Is it because of CORS not being enabled" — Does the Console of your browser's developer tools display a CORS related error message?

Comment: Solved the issue its seems like i was not allowing   CORS in the backend

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing response as json from axios raw response

```
axios.post('http://ec2-3-16-156-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/user/login', {
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(resJson=> {
          console.log(resJson);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Similar for your sign-up request